# Using code to detect IP address and change code depending on the IP Address

Tags: php, javascript, networking, routes, connection

I have a slight problem. I am using a website in PHP to call a webpage on my host site on Host Gator. The problem is that the URL points to my own IP address and is port forwarded to a specific PC on my LAN. It works perfectly unless it is me that is trying to access the webpage. I have to use the local IP address to access the same results that others can see. There is nothing I can do within my network, I am using Comcast Business with a static IP, when using my WAN IP address it simply doesn't leave the LAN and reflect back to the WAN IP.
So I was thinking of a couple of solutions:

One would be to use javascript or something to detect the requesting IP address, if the address is mine, it changes the URL to my local IP instead. That I do not know how to do.
The second choice was to use PHP on the hosted website to gather the results using:

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://MYWANURL);
echo $homepage;
```

Where MYWANURL my URL that can be accessed from the internet. The problem is this code comes back empty. I have never had problems using file_get_contents to get other websites from my host company.
If I use the same code when I am in my lan, using my lan address on a local php server, the output I am looking for works perfectly.

So my question is, is there a way via javascript OR PHP on my hosted company that I can use so that I can see the same results as people outside my LAN?

Comment: $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']; 
this gives the requesting ip address based on that u can redirect

Comment: Since it's a network problem, I'd rather fix the network than the code

Comment: Can you edit your hosts file to make this change?

Comment: Do you experience this problem only on one specific machine, or all of the hosts in your LAN suffer from this, too?

Comment: Its a lan problem that is unfix-able without making drastic changes within the hardware. I am using the Comcast Business router that lacks the settings to leave the LAN when referencing the public WAN address. So essentially when I query my own WAN (public address) it never leaves the LAN since it ties my LAN with the WAN address. It skips the IP Forwarding.

Comment: I used to get around that problem when I had a local DNS server, I would use computername.domain.com and it would route regardless if was witin the LAN or the internet. However, my DNS server is long gone from my LAN. The other option I was thinking was placing my home IP address in my host companies NS and see if it works. However, I am not sure If it will bring me the same failed results when it returns to my WAN address.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood your problem correctly, but I have the following setup (Ubuntu, in `/etc/hosts`)

```
127.0.0.1      yourhost.com
```

This way the packets will never leave your computer and will be immediately redirected to the named interface. Though, you have to port the same change to all hosts in your LAN if this is a problem with your router (or update your local DNS server if you use one)